# iris to screen calculation for eye tracking

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, eye-tracking

I'm currently experimenting with Eye tracking I've successfully built an iris tracking algorithm using OpenCV with contours and Hough transform. But the next step is unclear for me. I want to know if the calculations i'm doing are correct for translating the center of an eye to the screen. The head of the user has an fixed position.

[image: result]

What I want is an algorithm that works on all eyes off course. Is there like an angle calculation? So when the user is looking more to the right, linear?

What I do right now is:
 First I let the user look at specific points and use RANSAC to detect the iris position that's closest to the position on the screen. I do that with four 2D points on the screen and iris. I'm using Homography for this to get the correct calculation.

```
void gaussian_elimination(float *input, int n){
// ported to c from pseudocode in
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

float * A = input;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int m = n-1;
while (i < m && j < n){
    // Find pivot in column j, starting in row i:
    int maxi = i;
    for(int k = i+1; k<m; k++){
        if(fabs(A[k*n+j]) > fabs(A[maxi*n+j])){
            maxi = k;
        }
    }
    if (A[maxi*n+j] != 0){
        //swap rows i and maxi, but do not change the value of i
        if(i!=maxi)
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                float aux = A[i*n+k];
                A[i*n+k]=A[maxi*n+k];
                A[maxi*n+k]=aux;
            }
        //Now A[i,j] will contain the old value of A[maxi,j].
        //divide each entry in row i by A[i,j]
        float A_ij=A[i*n+j];
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
            A[i*n+k]/=A_ij;
        }
        //Now A[i,j] will have the value 1.
        for(int u = i+1; u< m; u++){
            //subtract A[u,j] * row i from row u
            float A_uj = A[u*n+j];
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                A[u*n+k]-=A_uj*A[i*n+k];
            }
            //Now A[u,j] will be 0, since A[u,j] - A[i,j] * A[u,j] = A[u,j] - 1 * A[u,j] = 0.
        }

        i++;
    }
    j++;
}

//back substitution
for(int i=m-2;i>=0;i--){
    for(int j=i+1;j<n-1;j++){
        A[i*n+m]-=A[i*n+j]*A[j*n+m];
        //A[i*n+j]=0;
    }
}
}



ofMatrix4x4 findHomography(ofPoint src[4], ofPoint dst[4]){
ofMatrix4x4 matrix;

// create the equation system to be solved
//
// from: Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision 2ed
//       Hartley R. and Zisserman A.
//
// x' = xH
// where H is the homography: a 3 by 3 matrix
// that transformed to inhomogeneous coordinates for each point
// gives the following equations for each point:
//
// x' * (h31*x + h32*y + h33) = h11*x + h12*y + h13
// y' * (h31*x + h32*y + h33) = h21*x + h22*y + h23
//
// as the homography is scale independent we can let h33 be 1 (indeed any of the terms)
// so for 4 points we have 8 equations for 8 terms to solve: h11 - h32
// after ordering the terms it gives the following matrix
// that can be solved with gaussian elimination:

float P[8][9]={
    {-src[0].x, -src[0].y, -1,   0,   0,  0, src[0].x*dst[0].x, src[0].y*dst[0].x, -dst[0].x }, // h11
    {  0,   0,  0, -src[0].x, -src[0].y, -1, src[0].x*dst[0].y, src[0].y*dst[0].y, -dst[0].y }, // h12

    {-src[1].x, -src[1].y, -1,   0,   0,  0, src[1].x*dst[1].x, src[1].y*dst[1].x, -dst[1].x }, // h13
    {  0,   0,  0, -src[1].x, -src[1].y, -1, src[1].x*dst[1].y, src[1].y*dst[1].y, -dst[1].y }, // h21

    {-src[2].x, -src[2].y, -1,   0,   0,  0, src[2].x*dst[2].x, src[2].y*dst[2].x, -dst[2].x }, // h22
    {  0,   0,  0, -src[2].x, -src[2].y, -1, src[2].x*dst[2].y, src[2].y*dst[2].y, -dst[2].y }, // h23

    {-src[3].x, -src[3].y, -1,   0,   0,  0, src[3].x*dst[3].x, src[3].y*dst[3].x, -dst[3].x }, // h31
    {  0,   0,  0, -src[3].x, -src[3].y, -1, src[3].x*dst[3].y, src[3].y*dst[3].y, -dst[3].y }, // h32
};

gaussian_elimination(&P[0][0],9);

matrix(0,0)=P[0][8];
matrix(0,1)=P[1][8];
matrix(0,2)=0;
matrix(0,3)=P[2][8];

matrix(1,0)=P[3][8];
matrix(1,1)=P[4][8];
matrix(1,2)=0;
matrix(1,3)=P[5][8];

matrix(2,0)=0;
matrix(2,1)=0;
matrix(2,2)=0;
matrix(2,3)=0;

matrix(3,0)=P[6][8];
matrix(3,1)=P[7][8];
matrix(3,2)=0;
matrix(3,3)=1;

return matrix;
```

}

Comment: Are you able to use both eyes, or to you have to support squint?

Comment: I'm currently tracking only one eye with this version. My goal is to interact with the screen buttons, so I'm using the eye as an cursor.

Comment: Well, this comment is more specific than the whole question, now we know what you want. It probably can be a little bit more complicated. A better explanation of your set up could be more helpful because the problem can be tackled of many ways. How you have your camera and your PC? Are you using the fixed camera of a laptop?

Comment: No, an Raspberry Pi combined with the  NoIR Camera Board - Infrared-sensitive Camera. The camera is  put on a fixed position. The screen is from a fixed position, to avoid complex calculations from iris to screen. The distance from the screen to the user is about an half a meter.

Comment: Tried to edit your code, but something seems to be wrong with parenthesis. Look at line number 19, 53 and the last one. Didn't want to edit it myself to not mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

**You should have a look at existing solutions for this:**

- Eye writer for painting with your eyes (I tested this to control the mouse only)

[Eyewriter.org](http://eyewriter.org)

[Eyewriter walkthrough](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-EyeWriter-20/)

[Eyewriter on Github](https://github.com/eyewriter/eyewriter)

- EyeLike pupil tracking

[EyeLike info page](http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/04/simple-accurate-eye-center-tracking-in-opencv/#fn:2) (algorithm similar to want you want is discussed here)

[EyeLike on Github](https://github.com/trishume/eyeLike)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

May be this [link](http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/04/simple-accurate-eye-center-tracking-in-opencv/) is helpful to you , best luck

```
cv::Mat computeMatXGradient(const cv::Mat &mat) {
  cv::Mat out(mat.rows,mat.cols,CV_64F);

  for (int y = 0; y < mat.rows; ++y) {
    const uchar *Mr = mat.ptr<uchar>(y);
    double *Or = out.ptr<double>(y);

    Or[0] = Mr[1] - Mr[0];
    for (int x = 1; x < mat.cols - 1; ++x) {
      Or[x] = (Mr[x+1] - Mr[x-1])/2.0;
    }
    Or[mat.cols-1] = Mr[mat.cols-1] - Mr[mat.cols-2];
  }

  return out;
}
```